# Changes does not affect on modal box height and weight

Tags: jquery, simplemodal

I am a simplemodal 1.3.5 user. I am currently using 2 different modals in my project. One is OK with default sizes but one must be bigger. I want to change modals width and height but script does not work somehow. What can be the problem? Here is my script...

```
$('#user_picture').modal({
    opacity:80,
    overlayCss: {backgroundColor:"#fff"},
    minHeight:600,
    minWidth: 600,
})
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing simplemodal that well, my guess would be that the minHeight and minWidth are only used when resizing the modal. Try using height: 600 and width:600 to set the width and height manually.

Edit:
Forgot to mention that height and width are set in the containerCss option like this:

```
containerCss:{
   height:600,
   width:600
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply Falle but it must work that way. Please see usage on project page. There is a working example on page's Examples part: http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/

Comment: Did you see my edit about how to set the height and width? I think this should work

Comment: Hey Falle, I just seen your update. Yes it did work. Thank you very much.